# TensorFLow Transfer Learning loading TFRecordDataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, transfer-learning, image-classification

I'm trying to follow the transfer learning, Jupyter notebook, tutorial to classify images of horses:

https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/images/transfer_learning.ipynb

I'm trying to build a local Tensorflow training pipeline in Docker, and have the latest 'TensorFlow Docker Image' installed.

I have 1000 labelled JPG images, 800x800, complete with bounding boxes and associated annotations.coco.json; split into train/validate/test folders.

I've managed to partially load the images and labels into TFRecordDatasets by converting the 'annotations.coco.json' into TFRecords using the 'create_coco_tf_record.py' script.

I'm struggling to understand how to transform/resize this data to feed into the training process, specifically:

- How to use the 'bounding box' data in the transformation/resize? The tutorial resizes the entire input image to 160x160 with no 'bounding box' data to handle.
- For example should i be cutting out the images contained within the bounding boxes, and resizing those to feed into the training process?
- Associated with the 'bounding boxes', each image can have several bounding boxes and therefore multiple labels per image; how do we handle these 'multiple labels' per image?
  Again the tutorial has one label per image so easier to understand in that respect.
- Is there a more appropriate tutorial to follow that covers handling 'bounding boxes' and 'multiple labels per image'?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this repo: https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2 to try and fine tune `yolov3`. It has a complete tutorial (https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2/blob/master/docs/training_voc.md) on how to retrain this `yolov3` object detector. It also supports "detecting different objects in images" (= your 'multiple labels per image', I think). Hopefully that will get you going, gl!

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Will do some reading and see what it reveals. I've actually managed to load the TFRecords, with the bounding boxes and multiple labels. Need to workout the next steps in the process.